# Source generator: Get actual type for FieldElement

Tags: dart, annotations, field, code-generation

So I've been playing around with code generation in Dart, and I have a problem resolving `Element` type in "data" classes. I have 2 data classes, and 2nd one has a type of a 1st one defined as a field.

`first.dart`:

```
part 'first.g.dart';

@Data(name="First")
class _First {
}
```

`second.dart`:

```
import 'first.dart';
part 'second.g.dart';

@Data(name="Second")
class _Second {
    First first;
}
```

You might have noticed, that `_Second` has field `First` instead of `_First`. That's because I generate two new classes. These two new classes contain additional functionality, like generated `hashCode` and some other custom methods I need.

In my `Generator` class, I need to obtain type string of field `first`. I'm doing this by `fieldElement.type?.getDisplayString()`. 
This works fine for all other non-generated classes, like `num` for example.
But in case of `first` field, returned type string is `"dynamic"`.

Is there a way to obtain correct type? Should `"First"` in this case.

`data_generator.dart`

```
class Data extends GeneratorForAnnotation<Data> {
    @override 
    generateForAnnotatedElement(Element element, ConstantReader annotation,
            BuildStep buildStep) {
        if(element is ClassElement) {
            FieldElement element = findField();
            String type = element.type?.getDisplayString();
            assert(type != "dynamic");
            //...
        }
    }
    //...
}
```